# Dropdown button inside navbar not working on angular cli

Tags: angular, web, command-line-interface, navbar, dropdown

I'm trying to use a dropdown button inside a navbar in angular cli but it simply won't work when I click it, I have already tried multiple code snippets and none of them actually works,but the problem is actually specific to the dropdown button which simply does not drop. I'm using ngx-bootstrap and my template code as well as the component.ts code are as follows:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Feel Good Inc.</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to add bunch of angular directives, look at the code below.
1) `dropdown` on li
2) `dropdownToggle` on anchor tag
3) `*dropdownMenu` on the div

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown>
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href dropdownToggle (click)="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
 aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```